# Should @transactional services be singleton or prototype in spring?

Tags: java, spring, singleton, prototype, spring-transactions

Will transaction management be a problem in spring if the service layer class is singleton? Or should it be prototype?

Comment: What makes you think it might be a problem?

Comment: No there is no such issue.

Comment: I thought the transaction would stay alive between multiple executions of the methods. Glad that is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that should not be a problem. What the `@Transactional` annotation will do is bind the Transaction lifecyle to the current thread. So each new thread will be run in a separate transaction.

So when your method is invoked, Spring will wrap that method call into a Transaction, so in a single threaded context, a transaction will start and commit  if the invocation is successful, and rollback (depending on your config) if an exception is thrown.

In a multithreaded context, each Thread will run in a separate transaction.